# sort one list of tuple and another list together

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, sorting

I have one object :

```
x= P(id1,type1,state1), y=P(id1,type2,state2)
```

and I create pair : (x,y)
and a dict :

```
dict[(type1,state1),(type2,state2)] = [id1,id2]
```

I want to sort keys by type and state and sort value in the same way.
To sort keys I do :

```
keys = sorted(tmpKeys, key=lambda element: (element.type,element.state))
```

for exemple, after sorted, if I obtain `(y,x)(keys=[(type2,state2),(type1,state1)]` in keys how can I have `value = [id2,id1]`.
How can I give to my dict values that is sort like keys ?

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? `foo = dict[(type1,state1),(type2,state2)]` raises a `TypeError`. Do you mean `dict([(type1,state1),(type2,state2)])` to call `dict()`?

Comment: oh yes ! dict[((type1,state1),(type2,state2))] sorry